# Download cover image of an album from app

Tags: android

I am implementing a mp3 player in android using `ExoPlayer`, the mp3 files I am getting theyr download URL connecting to a cloud and print them in a `RecyclerView` with an `ImageView` as `MP3 Icon` and an `EditText` where I set the name.

Is there a way to download a cover image from google or a professional website and set the `ImageView` with that Image ? If the method is taking too many resources I everytime the application start I can upload the file in cloud and taking them next time the app opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project called [Cover Art Archive](http://coverartarchive.org/) that is aimed to provide a repository of all well-known cover arts' images.

For using this resource you should use their [APIs](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/Cover_Art_Archive/API). Also [here](https://github.com/lastfm/coverartarchive-api) is a Java client for fetching images.

Comment: If I understand good I need to combine this library with MBID Library or database or what it uses for ID's right ?

Comment: @PavelMarian I haven't worked with this service but it seems that you should first obtain a MBID for your music and then using that Java library you can fetch image file. Also as I've read in their documentations, sounds like there is a database storing these MBIDs for musics. So you should someway (likely through an API) query that database for getting a proper MBID.